How to insert multiple selected records from a report into subform of a form in zoho creator?
I am developing a simple site inventory application in zoho creator. There are 2 forms in this case.
Form A: Material request .This form has a subform with fields for product and quantity
,Form B: Purchase Order.Has a subform with fields for product and quantity
In the purchase order form, I have to select the approved requests from the form A's report and after clicking 'create purchase order' button in that report , it should lead to the purchase order form and should auto populate the product and quantity fields.
How can I take multiple records and insert them into just one form?
I tried scripting  a few times. But I don't think my logic itself is right. Is there any way with which I would be able to auto populate the subform based on multiple records?

please share the form screenshot and some sample script for better understanding on the requirement
